# OpenGL rendering off by one pixel

Tags: c#, opengl, rendering, pixel, opentk

(I realize this question is also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608395/pixel-perfect-2d-rendering-with-opengl), but there were no answers that worked for me so I'm asking again in hopes that I get a working solution)

I'm using OpenGL to render a sort of data-viewing interface, and I need pixel-perfect rendering otherwise it just looks plain ugly.

The problem is on some graphics drivers OpenGL renders off by 1 pixel, in my case one to the left. Doing a translation of (0.375, 0.375) fixes it for primitives but it really badly blurs textures, and unfortunately that's unacceptable. How can I detect and/or fix the offsetted pixels without blurring textures?

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: I found a page on the OpenGL wiki which was very helpful, but I can' find it anymore :(. Anyway, why you can't use glCopyPixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines/points shade a fragment when the mathematical equation intersect a diamond inside that pixel. Polygons shade a fragment when the entire pixel is inside the polygon. Your fix is ok because no line/point falls exactly on the boundary of 2 pixels and offsets just enough so the polygons don't oscillate on a pixel boundary.

For your texture blurriness, you can either use the NEAREST filter or negatively offset your polygons with the same value.